# span inside div tag produces the multi text instead of inline text

Tags: html, internet-explorer

i want to display the text in inline (i.e. in single line) please refer below code.

```
<DIV id=container_vml_TrackToolTip style="POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 85px; TOP: 58px">
    <SPAN id=container_vml_ToolTipText style="FONT-SIZE: 12px; FONT-FAMILY: Segoe UI; POSITION: absolute; COLOR: yellow; FONT-STYLE: normal; LEFT: 414px; TOP: 126px; VISIBILITY: visible">2009  32</SPAN>
</DIV>
```

output produce the following result in IE browser.

[image]

i want to display the text inline instead of multi line in a particular position. how can i do this when placing span inside div tag ?

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: READ ABOUT NBSP / white-space prop

Comment: That may be the worst screen shot I've seen this week.

Comment: why you use uppercase?

Comment: Because the 1990s were fun.

Comment: Try this `2009&nbsp;32`

Answer (score 1):

try `white-space:nowrap`:

```
<DIV id=container_vml_TrackToolTip style="POSITION: absolute;LEFT: 85px; TOP: 58px"><SPAN id=container_vml_ToolTipText style="white-space:nowrap; FONT-SIZE: 12px; FONT-FAMILY: Segoe UI; POSITION: absolute; COLOR: yellow; FONT-STYLE: normal; LEFT: 414px; TOP: 126px; VISIBILITY: visible">2009  32</SPAN></DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the text to display inline you'll want to use a width: 100px in your span. For an example please take a look at 
[this version of the code.](http://jsfiddle.net/nyeung/Btytz/)

```
<span style="width: 100px; line-height: 20px .....">2009 32</span>
```